# Custom UICollectionViewLayout Error : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes copy sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a custom UICollectionViewLayout subclass. When prepareLayout is called, it creates the layout attributes for the cells and caches them, and then returns them at the appropriate times.  This all works correctly.

I recently added an override to shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange: so that when the layout changes proportions due to device rotation it will lay out nicely. What I am seeing now is that the app will sometimes crash with a message indicating: 
"[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes copy]: message sent to deallocated instance". This occurs when new data is received during the rotation event.

From what I can tell, this is happening because iOS is sending [copy] to the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes objects I returned from the layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: method after after the data has been received and prepareLayout has been called.  But what I don't understand is why iOS would not copy the item immediately if it was going to, or how I can retain it for an appropriate length of time after returning it without leaking memory.

So to recap:

```
- prepareLayout {
    self.myCellAttributes = [NSMutableArray array];

    // calculate UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for each cell, 
    // and store each in appropriate location ala:
    self.myCellAttributes[itemIndex]
}

- layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    // return appropriate attributes ala:
    return self.myCellAttributes[itemIndex];
}

-(BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    CGRect oldBounds = self.collectionView.bounds;
    return CGRectGetHeight(newBounds) != CGRectGetHeight(oldBounds);
}
```

My initial attempt to fix was:

```
-(void)prepareForAnimatedBoundsChange:(CGRect)oldBounds {
    self.retainedAttributes = self.myCellAttributes;
}
-(void)finalizeAnimatedBoundsChange {
    self.retainedAttributes = nil;
}
```

The thought there was that I would be retaining the objects that I had returned for the duration of the animation so if new data came in while that was happening, there wouldn't be an issue.  This did not have any apparent affect on the behavior, so I'm at a loss of how to ensure the attributes are retained for the correct amount of time.

So for the time being, I'm just returning NO for shouldInvalidateForBoundsChange, which removes the crash and works fine, with the exception that the cells 'snap' to the new size rather than smoothly transition.

Very grateful for any advice/suggestions/pointers.

Comment: You shouldn't need workarounds to make this work right. Can you show the full layout class?

Comment: Thanks @TimothyMoose. I took another look at this, and I think it has come down to a threading issue. As I said in my original description, this was happening when new data would be received while the collectionview was rotating. The data was being received via web service. I moved the web service response handling to a block on the mainQueue, and can't seem to reproduce this any more, so I think it was just that UICollectionView, like the rest of UIKit, needs to update on the main thread. Thanks for keeping me from chasing down a dead end.